# URL and SEO: letters (for shorter urls) vs words?

Tags: optimization, seo

which is better for url optimization:

`dictionary.com/w/apple` vs `dictionary.com/words/apple` ?

Comment: i heard being word insteade of letter on url, makes it more readable for Search engins. (but i'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple question: It depends on preference. If "Words" is a keyword you want to be indexed for, then include it in the URL. If not, minimize it down - it won't add to your SEO but it certainly won't detract from other areas of your strategy.